# How to get information about the source merge request in a squash commit?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I'm working on a CI pipeline in GitLab, for a project that has the following branching model:
[image]

Basically, once a merge request is created on a feature branch (commit 2), the CI pipeline will build artifacts with an automatic numbering system, which get uploaded to an artifact repository and deployed to a test environment. After code review and testing, we make more changes (commit 3) and the MR is approved. We then create a squash commit (because we like to do things that way).

Now, we want commit 4 (the squash commit on `main`) to get a git tag associating it with build 1.0.1+21, which is the last build number in the feature branch. But the squash commit doesn't appear to have any link back to the feature branch; it just looks like an independent push to the `main` branch.

How can I get a tag on commit 4 that associates it with the right build artifact?

Comment: "But the squash commit doesn't appear to have any link back to the feature branch" Correct. That's what a squash _is_. If you didn't want that to happen, you should not have chosen squashing. You have _deliberately_ elected not to have a true merge commit whose parentage leads back to the original commits forming the feature branch, and now you are _complaining_ that this is not a true merge.

Comment: On top of @matt's comment, also keep in mind that it happens _"because we like to do things that way"_.

Comment: You can adopt the common convention for squash commits to include information in the commit description to identify the commit that was squashed.

Comment: @matt I appreciate the insight, but not the scolding. I'm here to learn, and I appreciate answers and comments offering constructive advice.

Comment: I really don't think it's scolding. There's a reason why my comment has garnered four upvotes, namely, I put my finger right on the issue. And why is what I said any worse than "you're trying to have your cake and eat it too" and "Why do you want squash commits?", or "keep in mind that it happens "because we like to do things that way""? The point is the same throughout: Git is simply doing exactly what you told it to do, namely destroying an entire line of history. If you want something more constructive, sure: I suggest learning what Git is and what a merge is (and what a squash is).

Comment: @matt Your comment *was* right on the money. And I appreciated that. It was just the last sentence that I felt was uncalled-for. My only misconception was that I thought a squash still had some kind of link back to the original branch; now I know that it does not. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74446425/7850) gave me all the info I needed, in a completely respectful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We then create a squash commit (because we like to do things that way) [...] the squash commit doesn't appear to have any link back to the feature branch

That is because you're trying to have your cake and eat it too. It is by definition what squashing a to-be-merged branch into a single commit does: pretending the change has no history or parent branch, but suddenly appeared as a single commit.

Why do you want squash commits? If the answer contains the term "clean history", then you need to learn to rebase your feature branches to squash and reorder WIP commits instead.

I am not in favor of squashing entire features, because this will harm productivity in the long run, as I find commit messages to be part of your documentation and thought process. If you have other mechanisms in place for this, close to the source code, it may be defendable, but still, it causes more problems (merge conflicts and thrown away code being a major one) than to me it appears to solve.

As for your question: then you need to revise the process that creates these squash commits to include build tags made on the feature branch. Either delete the tag and create a new one, or include some phrasing in the commit message.

Comment: Thanks, this describes the issue very well! So, if I decide to use merge commits rather than squash commits, is there a GitLab CI variable available to me that links back to the feature branch?

Comment: @ShaulBehr If you use merge commits, the merge commit's second parent *is* the pointer to the feature branch.

Comment: I don't know about what is available in GitLab CI.... what I do know is that you should be able to see the commit that was originally merged (the tip of the branch back then) by using `the-merge-commit^2`.